# Select New Worksheet Each Time Array Changes

Tags: c#

I am creating an array, and writing to an Excel Spreadsheet.  For each different element of the array, I want to select the next worksheet.  For example, element1 of the array should write to sheet1, element2 would write to sheet2 etc etc.  What is the syntax for this to happen?  Would something like this work, as the 1st worksheet should already be select when the workbook launches, then this will select each subsequent sheet based off the value of wsCount.  Does this look effective to the smarties here?

```
int wsCount = 0;
//for each loop here
foreach (string n in DogNames)
{
if (wsCount == 1)
{
    Sheets[2].Select();
}
if (wsCount == 2)
{
    Sheets[3].Select();
}
if (wsCount == 3)
{
    Sheets[4].Select();
}
//Do stuff here
wsCount++;
}
```

Comment: You can rely on the `Sheets` collection. Example: `WorkSheet curSheet =  workBook.Sheets[count]` (where `count` is the counter in the loop). If you need more help, please post the code you have tried and be more specific.

Comment: @varocarbas TY, I will toy with this code and get it as close as I can before posting back.  I wasn't sure where to begin so thank you very much for a starting point!

Comment: @varocarbas  -- please check my code snippet and provide feedback :)

Comment: You got the idea. But you should do the code a bit smaller, for example: `for(int wsCount = 0; wsCount < DogNames.Count; wsCount++)
{
    if (wsCount >= 1 && wsCount <= 3)
    {
        Sheets[wsCount + 1].Select();
    }
}`

Comment: And would this go above or below my foreach loop?  Or are we replacing the foreach loop with the syntax above?

Comment: My code above emulates exactly what your loop does. I used `for`, instead of `foreach` because you are interested in the indices (and thus `for` is more adequate). And then I converted your three conditions into just one by applying the (clear) pattern, that is: current counter + 1 equals the sheet index. See... this has got already too long for comments (-> not clear for future readers). Your question has been answered; I have even proposed an improved version of your algorithm. If you have problems to understand some parts of my answer, perhaps you should post a new question.

Comment: PS: although bear in mind the "minimum knowledge" requirement. Because I am afraid that not understanding that the code I proposed performs the same actions than yours would imply a general programming knowledge below what is expected in SO. And thus perhaps you should analyse the code more carefully or do some research before asking such a question here (i.e., do both codes perform the same actions?), because it might be off-topic.